# Writing go programs like node.js apps without go path

Tags: go

Upon learning the basics of go I realise I need this root gocode directory to export as GOPATH, I would much rather simply be able to have a project folder, which I can install packages into, and run my go code from within, is this seriously how they've programmed go to be.. who likes this?

I've looked at the vendor folder option but that still means needing a gocode GOPATH export and the vendor directories need to be in that source folder structure.

I want my project to be the root and that's it. How can that not be possible with go lang?

Or is it?

Comment: First and foremost, don't try to use Go like NodeJS, because it isn't like NodeJS. Is there some particular reason you don't want to use Go as it is intended?

Comment: because I want to be able to have a project folder, be the root of that project, not use a global go language specific root folder. It seems limiting?

Comment: Limiting in what way? If you're concerned about dependency management, you can use vendoring (either the built-in functionality or one of many third-party tools).

Comment: I have to put my projects inside the root go folder, I don't want to do that, is it possible not to?

Comment: It's possible, by changing your gopath depending on what project you're working on, but I can't imagine it's worth it. You can choose what your workspace path is, and every project can be at a separate path under that directory. It's the same as having a "projects" directory where you have all your repos checked out, you just have to tell Go where it is with an environment variable.

Comment: Alternatively, you can have your go files in what every directory you like, and then link this directory in your `$GOPATH/src` directory. E.g on linux:
`mkdir $HOME/myproject` and put all your files there. Then you can `ln -s $HOME/myproject $GOPATH/src` to be able to install (build or what every you like) the project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to set your GOPATH, and all your go-code, -binaries, -packages etc will be placed in this folder. You can make a folder in the root of `$GOPATH/src`, e.g `$GOPATH/src/myapp` and then create a file within this folder. Example myapp.go

```
package main

import fmt
func main() {
    fmt.Print("My app")
}
```

Compile it with `go install $GOPATH/src/myapp/myapp.go` and run it with `$GOPATH/bin/myapp`.

Comment: But I would mention that go used the idea of re-using packages, and relies heavily on git in this manner. So a lot of packages that you will use in you project(s) will also be stored in the `src`-folder. And I would recommend you to use the go-convention if you're planning to use git.